# Equation numbered two times

Tags: align

Using the align function, I get that my equation placed on two lines is numbered two times.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{malmoe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{align}
E_{t-1}[r_{i,t}] = &\,\phi_{i,t-1}\,\lambda_{t-1}\,cov_{t-1}[r_{i,t},r_{w,t}]\,+\\                                      
&(1 - \phi_{i,t-1})\,\lambda_{i,t-1}\,var_{t-1}[r_{i,t}]
        \end{align}         
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you're splitting the equation ... each line is numbered, unless you use `\nonumber\\\`  for the first one or `\nonumber` for the second one, depending on which line should be numbered

Comment: Would you like the numbering to be on the first line, second line, or in between the first and second line?

Comment: Thanks all for you prompt reply. @Troy, Denis's code works well for between lines. What if I want to the numbering to be on the second line? (just for the purpose of learning)

Comment: @Alan You can use Christian's method. Use `\nonumber` or `\notag` before you skip the line with `\\ `. It basically tells LaTeX that you don't want the first line to be numbered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{malmoe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E_{t-1}[r_{i,t}] = &\,\phi_{i,t-1}\,\lambda_{t-1}\,cov_{t-1}[r_{i,t},r_{w,t}]\,+\\
&(1 - \phi_{i,t-1})\,\lambda_{i,t-1}\,var_{t-1}[r_{i,t}]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```